# Change name attribute of input/select field nested in a cloned table for dynamic form entry - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm designing a dynamic input form that essentially acts as a user GUI for creating tables in a mysql database.

**The Javascript**

```
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('poptemplate').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var fieldname = newField[i].name;
        if (fieldname){
            newField[i].name = fieldname + counter;
            }
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('catidtable');
    insertHere.parentNode.appendChild(newFields);
    }
window.onload = moreFields;
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="poptemplate" style="display: none" >
<table border="3">
<tr>
    <td>Field Name:</td>
    <td><input class="renameme" form="catform" type="text" name="fieldname_input" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Data Type:</td>
    <td><?php $typedown->displayList(); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input type="button" value="Remove Field" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**The Problem**

The problem is that when new fields are added to the form, they retain the same name designators from the original clone. (Clone structure is 'poptemplate' div in code above.)

Having taught myself most of my web developing skills from research, I have located this script, now modified, (original source: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html) in order to clone the template and insert it into the page (with an unshown jquery function that merely calls the JS function when the Add Field button is clicked).

The problem is, the JS, while it clones the DIV successfully and places it, the loop involved does not delve deep enough into the node structure of my template to find the input fields and change their names.

One input field is a drop-down list that is populated through a mysql query with php, however its location in the node structure should be at the same level as the text input.
(i.e. `<Table><tr><td><input(or/)select>`)

**The Attempt At Fixing Part 1**

```
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('poptemplate').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes; //Table level of poptemplate
    if (newField.hasChildNodes()){//If the table has children, and it does, loop through them
     for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var x = newField.rows[i].cells.length; //how many cells you got in your row
            if (x>0;){ //if its more than 0, look at the cells
            for (var r = 0;r<x;r++) {
                var td = newField.rows[0].cell[r]; //td is equal to the td level time to check to see if it has input or select
                    var k = td.getElementsByTagName("select");
                    if (k.hasChildren()){
                    k.firstChild.setAttribute(name, name + counter);
                    }
                    var p = td.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    if (p.hasChildren()){
                    p.firstChild.setAttribute(name, name + counter);
                    }
                                    }
                    }
                                        }
}                                           
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('catidtable');
    insertHere.parentNode.appendChild(newFields);
}
window.onload = moreFields;
```

**Attempt At The Fix Part 2**

After following through with a suggestion from `briansol`, I have the following modified java script that still does not follow through with what it is supposed to do on execution. I have left the unnecessary, however useful, line of code  `inputs[index].value =  inputs[index].name + counter;` for troubleshooting purposes.

```
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var index, inputs;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('poptemplate').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = newFields.id+counter;
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('catidtable');
    insertHere.parentNode.appendChild(newFields);
    // now update it
    container = document.getElementById(newFields.id+counter);
    // Find its child `input` elements
    inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    selects = container.getElementByTagName('select');
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        // deal with inputs[index] element.
        inputs[index].name =  inputs[index].name + counter;
        inputs[index].value =  inputs[index].name + counter;
    }
    for (index = 0; index < selects.length; ++index) {
        // deal with select element
        selects[index].name = selects[index].name + counter;
        }
 }
window.onload = moreFields;
```

**The Need**
UPDATED:

Currently, Attempt 2 seems promising but there is something missing. It successfully clones the template, but the procedures to capture the select and input elements is not succeeding.

ORIGINAL:

I'm looking for a solution to patch the already provided **for** loop to delve deeper, **or** alternative code that doesn't break the cloning process, but additionally changes the name attributes. All of my attempts to modify this code to traverse deeper have resulted in the code breaking on execution.

This is my first post here, I have found stackoverflow to be incredibly helpful, I hope my problem and its solution can help others learn and understand better. Thanks for assistance in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to include code locally.*

You'll need to clone not only the rows, but also give each item a unique name for the form to post or you'll over-write data.  Each field name must be unique.

easy was is to use a counter on the clone copy.

Here's a sample:

```
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
while(counter<10){
counter++;
var index, inputs;
var newFields = document.getElementById('poptemplate').cloneNode(true);
newFields.id = 'clone'+counter;
newFields.style.display = 'block';
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
 var insertHere = document.getElementById('catidtable');
insertHere.parentNode.appendChild(newFields);
// now update it
container = document.getElementById('clone'+counter);
// Find its child `input` elements
inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
    inputs[index].name =  inputs[index].name + counter;
    inputs[index].value =  inputs[index].name + counter;
}   
}
}
window.onload = moreFields;



<div id="poptemplate" style="display:none">
<table border="3" id="template">
<tr>
    <td>Field Name:</td>
    <td><input class="renameme" form="catform" type="text" name="fieldname_input" />    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr1">
    <td id="td1" colspan='2'><input type="button" value="Remove Field" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>

<table id="catidtable">
</table>
```

Comment: here's a VERY quick demo that needs work, but does expemplify the job.   http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/pyq8v/   it puts the clone in the dom as is, then alters it based on the ID of the table.  This may not be as efficient, but it's easier to address the lements once they actually exist.    I ran it 10 times to show that the fields do get updated.

Comment: Could you put the code in the answer, not just a jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

I'm indebted to `briansol` for helping with the structural example. This code is a functioning solution to my problem. Edits from briansol's original code example includes removal of `+ counter` from the `container` assignment. Firefox's developer console allowed me to see that the variable was coming up null. Once the counter had been added to the ID, there was no need to append it again.

**The Solution**

```
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('poptemplate').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = newFields.id+counter;
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('catidtable');
    insertHere.parentNode.appendChild(newFields);
    // now update it
    var index, inputs, selects, container;
    container = document.getElementById(newFields.id);
    // Find its child `input` elements
    inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    selects = container.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        // deal with inputs[index] element.
        inputs[index].name =  inputs[index].name + counter;
    }
    for (index = 0; index < selects.length; ++index) {
        // deal with select element
        selects[index].name = selects[index].name + counter;
        }
}
window.onload = moreFields;
```

Comment: glad this got you going :)  I struggled with this the first time i cloned too.