# Multiple rows to database, not adding

Tags: javascript, php, database, rows

I found this script to add rows to my form somewhere and I can add rows that works, the only problem is that when I submit it, only the first row are submitted. Never tried anything like this before so I might be completely off and if that is the case at least I will know that.

THIS IS THE HTML

```
<form name="addshow" action="addshow.php" method="post">
       <input type="submit" value="Lägg till">
       <input type="reset" value="Nollställ"/>
       <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#add").click(function() {
                      $('#tableclassen tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tableclassen tbody>tr:last');
                      return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <a  id="add">+</a>
            <TABLE id='tableclassen' cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <TBODY>
                <TR valign="top">
                    <TD width>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="Horse_id" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange ID')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="5"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Årtal" name="years" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange årtal')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="6"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Plac." name="place" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange placering')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="4"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ange eventnamn" name="event" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange eventnamn')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="35"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ange klass" name="class" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange klass')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Assoc." name="association" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange Assoc.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="6"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Poäng" name="points" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange poänh')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="3"/>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <select name="type" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Välj typ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Välj typ</option>
                        <option value="SWE">SWE</option>
                        <option value="INTER">INTER</option>
                    </select>
                    </TD>

                    <TD>
                    <select name="dis">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Välj Dis</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="SJ">SJ</option>
                        <option value="E">E</option>
                        <option value="U">U</option>
                        <option value="K">K</option>
                        <option value="T">T</option>
                    </select>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>

            </form>
```

THIS IS THE PHP/DATABASE PROCESS

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include("function/conn.php"); //Databas koppling
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

$Horse_id = addslashes($_POST['Horse_id']);
$Year = addslashes($_POST['years']);
$Place = addslashes($_POST['place']);
$Event = addslashes($_POST['event']);
$Class = addslashes($_POST['class']);
$Assoc = addslashes($_POST['association']);
$Point = addslashes($_POST['points']);
$Type = addslashes($_POST['type']);
$Dis = addslashes($_POST['dis']);
//Sparar värden i variabler ifrån form


$result = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO shows 
                        (Horse_id, years, place, event, class, association, points, type, dis) 
                        VALUES('$Horse_id', '$Year', '$Place', '$Event', '$Class', '$Assoc', '$Point', '$Type', '$Dis') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
// Lägger in ny post i databasen

if ($result){ //Skicka tillbacka användaren till backend
header("location: admin.php");
}
else{
echo "Something went wrong.";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the form fields array-style names, e.g.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="Horse_id[]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Ange ID')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" size="5"/>
```

Then in PHP, `$_POST['Horse_id']` will be an array of all the inputs; the server script can loop through them and insert them all in the DB. If you use the same name in all rows without `[]`, `$_POST['Horse_id']` will only contain the last one.

Comment: I have seen this before the wierd thing is, that as soon as i add [] to the fields making them array-styled it doesn't send anything to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you don't change the name'ed field of the cloned inputs and the back-end only takes the last one in most cases.

I left an example in a similar topic:  [Change name attribute of input/select field nested in a cloned table for dynamic form entry - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205596/change-name-attribute-of-input-select-field-nested-in-a-cloned-table-for-dynamic/24209208#24209208)

Comment: I tried to understand that example but can't really wrapp my head around it.

Comment: The core issue is that you have <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="Horse_id"  and then when you clone it, you get another <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="Horse_id"   .  This is invalid HTML.  the clone needs to be something else, like <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="Horse_id2"   

Adding the counter it it helps make the names unique.  You then need to account for the clone count (perhaps a hidden field to post as well) and loop through it in the backup N times.    The other answer from Barmar uses [] lists, which is the same concept basically but different method.

Comment: I have tried both answers now and none of them seem to work, at least I can't get them to work. as soon as I try to use any of them nothing is sent to the database.